# Facebook Authentication Firebase with React JS - Providers Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use Firebase Authentication to login with Facebook with React JS. I leave the firebaseSample.ts and config.ts files below.

I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined" on the React JS side. The line is exactly that.

- facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()

In some posts "import * as firebase from "firebase/app";" I've seen related articles for changing the import structure.

import * as firebase from "firebase"; was said to be. However, when I do it this way, I get an error on the initializeApp side.

**firebaseSample.ts**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import config from 'config/config';

const FirebaseSample = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase);

export const Providers = {
facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export default FirebaseSample;
```

**config.ts**

```
const config = {
firebase: { 
  apiKey: "unique_id",
  authDomain: "unique_id",
  databaseURL: unique_id",
  projectId: "unique_id-1663e",
  storageBucket: "unique_id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "unique_id",
  appId: "1:unique_id",
  measurementId: "G-unique_id"
  }
}
export default config;
```

**Updated** **firebaseSample.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import config from 'config/config';

const FirebaseSample = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase);

export const Providers = {
facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
}

 export const auth = firebase.auth();
 export default FirebaseSample;
```

- After updating the import files in the firebaseSample.ts file, I started getting the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Providers". I am attaching it as a screenshot.

[image]

**Updated 2.0** **firebaseSample.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import config from 'config/config';

const FirebaseSample = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase);

const Providers = {
  facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
 }

   export Providers;    

  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  export default FirebaseSample;
```

**Last Update and Information**

I resolved the error by updating the firebase import structure in the whole project.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
```

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: `export { Providers }` <- those `{}`. To import that in other components: `import { Providers } from "../path/to/firebaseSample.ts"`

Comment: Providers is not a component.

Comment: There's isn't any code that shows how you are using the imported `Providers`. Can you add that in the question?

Comment: I didn't do anything extra for Providers.
I am using the reference here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#web-version-9

Comment: I'm already working on firebaseSample.ts.
import { Providers } from "../path/to/firebaseSample.ts" I don't understand why I need to import it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new version if Firebase SDK. The version 9 you would need to change your imports to:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
```

Or use the new syntax according to the new Firebase SDK 9. The `compat` imports allow you to still use the old syntax.

Can you also try to write this:

```js
export const Providers = {
  facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
}
```

like this:

```js
const Providers = {
  facebook: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
}

export { Providers }
```

Comment: I updated the imports as you specified and got the error below.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined

However, I started getting the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Providers".

Comment: Can you pls update your question with the latest code and a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Can you pls check the updated answer with the last part about the export.

Comment: I re-added the firebaseSample.ts file as Updated 2.0 and got an error. I share it in the question section. Thanks

Comment: As @Dharmaraj edited the answer. We forgot to put the `{}` around `Providers` as it is a named export. Can you pls try it again with that change.

Comment: Do you still have the same error? If you have a different error pls keep in mind that we are not here to debug your code. We can help only with one issue/error per question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help.